# Computing velocity as a function of time

Tags: kinematics

I have measured the amount of time (5 ms) it takes a projectile to travel 1 meter. I make the following assumptions:

- $1$-D motion.
- the only force acting on the projectile is a force due to drag, $F(t)$.
- the force due to drag is simply proportional to the square of the velocity, e.g., $F(t) = Cv(t)^2$.

Do I have enough information to compute the velocity as a function of time? Thanks!

Comment: You need to know the mass of the projectile and the initial velocity.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelCohen, that's what I was afraid of. I could probably weigh the projectile or compute the mass somehow, but I have no way of measuring the initial velocity. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know the mass $m$ of the projectile (you can weigh it), and with your current data you will need to know what $C$ is. You can either do this by

- Looking up the drag coefficient for the projectile, measuring the cross sectional area of the projectile and the density of the medium it is going through.
- Making another simultaneous measurement (i.e. measuring the amount of time it takes to make another distance).

In either case, we wish to solve the ODE
$$x''(t)=-\frac{C}{m}(x'(t))^2,$$
where $x$ is the position. Substituting $v=x'$ and solving the ODE by separation of variables gives
$$v(t)=\frac{m}{Ct-K_1 m},$$
where $K_1$ is a constant to be determined. Substituting back and integrating gives
$$x(t)=\frac{m}{C}\log|Ct-K_1 m|+K_2,$$
where $K_2$ is another constant to be determined. We have the boundary data $x(0)=0$ and $x(0.005)=1$. From the first boundary condition, we obtain $K_2=-\frac{m}{C}\log|K_1 m|$. This results in
$$x(t)=\frac{m}{C}\log\left|\frac{Ct-K_1 m}{K_1 m}\right|.$$
The second boundary condition results in the condition
$$\left|\frac{0.005 C-K_1 m}{K_1 m}\right|=e^{C/m},$$
which has two solutions
$$K_1\in \left\{-\frac{0.005C}{m(e^{C/m}-1)},\quad \frac{0.005C}{m(1+e^{C/m})}\right\},$$
but the first solution is the only physical solution (otherwise the initial velocity is negative, and the velocity will diverge at a certain time). Hence the solution is given by
$$x(t)=\frac{m}{C}\log\left(200(e^{C/m}-1)t+1\right), \tag{1}$$
$$v(t)=\frac{200m(e^{C/m}-1)}{200C(e^{C/m}-1)t+C}.$$
You now need to know $C$. The first approach is straightforward (i.e. use the [well-known equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation) $F=\frac{1}{2}\rho C_D A v^2$). If you are opting for the latter approach, you can measure the time it takes to make another distance (e.g. $2$ metres) to obtain a third boundary condition and then solve for $C$ in $(1)$. For this, you can use a numerical [root-finding method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#:%7E:text=Most%20numerical%20root%2Dfinding%20methods,accurate%20approximation%20to%20the%20root.) such as the Newton-Raphson method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about the information you have. From Newton's 2nd Law, you can say that $m\dot v\hat v=-cv^2\hat v$. This is an easy ODE to solve, but you don't have any information about the initial velocity, so this method won't work. However, you can also write Newton's 2nd Law in terms of position, that is, $m\ddot x\hat x=-c\dot x^2 \hat x$. This is a second order ODE, and you have two initial conditions for the position, $x(0\ \mathrm{ms})=0\ \mathrm{m}$, and $x(5\ \mathrm{ms})=1\ \mathrm{m}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This works, but only if the OP actually knows the value of $C$.

Comment: Thanks, Jake! I will certainly need to refer to some ODE textbooks, but I probably have a fighting chance of solving that. Though I don't know C, I should be able to estimate/calculate that value...this is actually a 38 cal bullet travelling through air.

Comment: I think you could calculate $C$ by measuring the amount of time it takes to make another distance (e.g. 2 metres). You will probably need a numerical root finding method to do this though.

Comment: Thanks, @projectilemotion! That is good to know. It would not be difficult to set up to get a simultaneous measurement over a different distance.

Comment: You should be able to find a value for $C$ in a table somewhere. Drag coefficients (for the most part) only rely on the cross-sectional area of the object and the density of the fluid it's moving through.